# no module found for an installed app

Tags: python, django, django-manage.py, manage.py

I have made my template folder as an app in my python web application
and I mentioned it in my INSTALLED_APPS 
I also have the init file in the template folder, but when I'm running manage.py tasks, there is an error and manage.py doesn't find this app, even there is no error when I'm putting the app into INSTALLED_APPS dictionary.
any help?

Comment: settings.py codes please

Comment: Why would you do this? :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `manage.py tasks` is, must be from some extension you have installed. However what you are asking doesn't make much sense. An app, at a minumum, has a `models.py` file, which presumably your templates folder doesn't have. But there is of course no reason at all to treat your templates folder as an app. Put the folder into `TEMPLATE_DIRS` instead.